# Unable to use jquery plugin using higher version of jquery, while loading two versions of jquery simultaneously

Tags: jquery, plugins, multiple-instances, multiple-versions

Our project is running on jquery 1.3.2, yes a very old version, I know. Anyways, we are not going to upgrade that right now. We just need to use jquery's [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) (Download link - https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) right now, which needs jquery 1.4 at least. So, I followed the following solution to load both versions of jquery on the same page -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/351903

But I am not able to call chosen on the newer version of jquery. Here is what I did -

*1. In the jquery loading part*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Added for using jQuery chosen plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_4 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Note - I **did not write** the following for the older version of jquery , because I did not want to replace wherever I have written anything like `$("something").somefunc()` with this `jQuery_1_3_2("something").somefunc()` -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

*2. And then, in the plugin calling part*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/chosen.css"/>
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_4(document).ready(function() 
{
    jQuery_1_4("select#user_id").chosen();  //Trying to call chosen on the newer version of jquery
});
</script>
```

But I am getting this error `jQuery_1_4("select#user_id").chosen is not a function`.

However this is working properly - `alert("see"+jQuery_1_4("select#user_id").attr("id"));`.

So, the problem seems to be only while using the plugin and may be I have to do some tweak inside the plugin code, may be replace some `$`s with `jQuery_1_4`? But that does not sound good and I am not sure what is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your old version as default, You should do `var jQuery = $.noConflict(true);` immediately after loading old version.  However, you still need to check your `$("something").somefunc()` calls

Comment: Thanks. It seems the newer version should be included first, as given in http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/ . I just needed to edit one line in my plugin file - `$ = jQuery;` to  `$ = jQuery_1_4;`. And I guess all my previous jquery things are working fine. I just randomly checked a few and they are working.

Answer (score 0):

call noConflict() BEFORE including the second version of jQuery